# Why is the difference of a stream function at two points the flow rate PER UNIT WIDTH?

Tags: physics, fluid-dynamics

For a velocity vector field $\bf{u}$$ = (u,w)$ in two dimensions ($x$ and $z$), we define the stream function $\psi$ to be; $$\psi(P_1) = \int_{P_0}^{P_1} \mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{n}dl$$ where $P_0$ is a fixed point and the integral is along a contour from $P_0$ to $P_1$ (conditions are required s.t it doesn't matter which contour we choose). Then for points $P_1$ and $P_2$ it is claimed in various references that $\psi(P_2)-\psi(P_1)$ is the flow rate $\bf{per ~unit~ width}$ between $P_2$ and $P_1$.

My issue is with the unit width part of the statement and I'll give an example to illustrate my problem. In order for the choice of contour not to matter it is shown that we need $$\frac{\partial w}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} =0$$ This is fulfilled if we have everywhere a constant vector field. Now choose a point A s.t. the straight line between $P_0$ and A is perpendicular  to the constant vector field. Then $$\psi(A)-\psi(P_0) = \psi(A)-0 =  \int_{P_0}^{A} \mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{n}dl =\int_{P_0}^{A} |\mathbf{u}|dl = |\mathbf{u}|\cdot|\bar{AP_0}|$$

But this would be the total rate of flow between $A$ and $P_0$, not the flow rate per unit width.

Comment: What references make this claim? Batchelor says the $\psi(P_1)-\psi(P_0)$ is the volume flux across any curve joining $P_0$ and $P_1$ (and others do to, according to Wikipedia).

Comment: @David thanks for your comment. It says it in Dean and Dalrymples 'water wave mechanics for scientists and engineers' and also in Nellis and Kleins 'Heat transfer'. However, having re-read the latter's take on it I think that what has happened is that they are assuming axis symmetric three dimensional flow. I was considering the two dimensional flow rate, but the total flux across the given line will also be the volumetric rate per unit width if we are considering three dimensional axis symmetric flow.

Comment: so the 'per unit width' bit I was worrying about was not referring to the line between P1 and P2, but perpendicular to it as a third dimension.

Comment: The flux=difference in streamfunction thing works in 2D, but I don't know anything about 3D streamfunctions. I get what you are saying about it being 'per unit width' in the 3rd dimension when considering 3D flow.